# How to increment counter in for loop for python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, count

I'm just trying to increment a simple counter in my for loop, but this function always returns 54.  I'm guessing it does this because it sees the second counter as a local variable inside the for loop.  How can I increment the counter?? I feel like this should be really simple since python is supposedly a straight-forward language.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
for line in train_instances:
    counter = 54
    a = (line.split(":")[0])[i]
    b = (line.split(":")[1])[1]
    if ((int(a) == X) and (int(b) == Y)):
        counter = counter + 1
return counter
```

Comment: because you assign it to `counter = 54` on _each_ iteration?

Answer (score 4):

Use `emumerate` instead .

```
for counter,line in enumerate(train_instances):
    a,b = line.split(":")
```

Don't increment anything in the loop or reset `counter` at all

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the initial declaration of the counter outside the for loop.  Since it's inside, each time you loop through, the counter is getting reset to 54 each time.

Answer (score 3):

It is doing so because the counter variable is in the body of the loop and every time the loop runs, the counter variable is re-declared and assigned the value 54. Why don't you move the counter variable just above the for loop so it returns the right value like in the code below.

```
counter = 54

for line in train_instances:
    a = (line.split(":")[0])[i]
    b = (line.split(":")[1])[1]

    if ((int(a) == X) and (int(b) == Y)):
        counter = counter + 1
return counter
```

Answer (score 2):

You should initialise `counter` before the loop. Your current code sets `counter` to 54 every loop.